# mkdir(): Not a directory PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a path with codeigniter on PHP and I'm getting this php error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: mkdir(): Not a directory
Filename: devotee/acc.devotee.php
Line Number: 81
```

Here is the line of code that php is complaining about

```
    // Set cache settings
    $this->_cache_path = $this->EE->config->item('devotee_monitor_cachepath') ? $this->EE->config->item('devotee_monitor_cachepath') : APPPATH . 'cache/devotee/';
    $this->_cache_time = 60 * 60; // 1 hour

    // Create cache folder if it doesn't exist

    if(! is_dir($this->_cache_path))
    {
        mkdir($this->_cache_path, DIR_WRITE_MODE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, in addition to checking what `$this->_cache_path` is resolving to as Bassem Samir mentions, make sure that your param to mkdir() does not have a trailing slash. For example,

```
mkdir("some_dir");
```

... Works

Whereas

```
mkdir("some_dir/");
```

... Doesn't work.

In other words, mkdir() will expect something to follow the slash: the sub folder. If not present, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the content of `$this->_cache_path`. It can be empty so mkdir throws warning message.